# What Does "Export-Package: ." Mean?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle, manifest.mf

Imagine an Eclipse plug-in (resp. OSGi bundle) with a package `org.acme.foo.bar`.

It's possible to export "." e.g. see the following *MANIFEST.MF* snippet:

```
Export-Package: .,
 org.acme.foo.bar
```

Compiler has no problems with that so it seems to be a legit export.

What does it do? What is the difference to the following ("." not exported)?

```
Export-Package: org.acme.foo.bar
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.` is the **default package** but according to the [OSGi Core, Release 6 specification](https://osgi.org/download/r6/osgi.core-6.0.0.pdf) **`.` is not a valid value for `Export-Package`** because a package name must start with a letter:

> Export-Package ::= export ( ',' export)*
>  export ::= package-names
>   ( ';' parameter )*
>  package-names ::= package-name ( ';'
>   package-name )*
>  **package-name ::=** unique-name
>  unique-name ::=
>   **identifier ( '.' identifier )***
>  **identifier ::= jletter**
>   jletterordigit *
>  jletter ::= <see [Java Language Specification
>   Third Edition for *JavaLetter*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/lexical.html)>
>  jletterordigit ::= <see
>   [Java Language Specification Third Edition for
>   *JavaLetterOrDigit*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/lexical.html)>

It would therefore be better to do without a default package:

```
Export-Package: org.acme.foo.bar
```

Comment: Correct except that it does not depend on the OSGi Framework used. Exporting the default package is an error under all spec-compliant framework implementations.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Thank you for clarifying. I edited my answer accordingly. Does this mean that ignoring `.` or non-existing packages and interpreting `.` as a default package violates the spec? Does the spec allow a non-exported default package?

Comment: `.` is an invalid package name. The default package has no name and, of course, cannot be imported or exported from a bundle.

Answer (score 3):

Although the Eclipse MANIFEST.MF validation allows '.' it isn't valid according to the OSGi specification. It seems to mean the default package, but this isn't a sensible thing to export.

This appears to be confirmed by Eclipse bug [366800](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=366800) which reported the use of a '.' like this in the 'org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.query' plugin. The bug was accepted as a error and the '.' removed.

Comment: `.` is the default package (which should be avoided) and in the referenced bug added by mistake to a plug-in/bundle not containing a default package. Are you sure the OSGi specification does not allow to specify the default package as an exported package?

Comment: OK, so this seems to be Eclipse specific and doesn't really seem to make much sense.

Comment: I don't think `. ` is Eclipse specific (e. g. see [_"default package '.'"_ here](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html)) but I agree using a default package is ugly and maybe not covered by the OSGi specification.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find it in the OSGi Spec (V6).

Tried an example in Eclipse (Oygen.2). Created two plug-ins (aka bundles), one "provider", the other "consumer".
Provider exports default package and in that package contains a public Class A.

=> It's not possible to access A from plug-in "provider". Eclipse suggests to export package `''`. Invoking that option doesn't change anything. Compile error remains.

I would recommend not to use this.